# Prove $\|x\|+\|y\|+\|z\|+\|x+y+z\| \ge \|x+y\|+\|y+z\|+\|z+x\|$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, vector-spaces

Assuming $x,y,z$ are complex numbers, or vectors, prove 
$$\|x\|+\|y\|+\|z\|+\|x+y+z\| \ge \|x+y\|+\|y+z\|+\|z+x\|$$

I've tried replacing $x+y$, $y+z$, $z+x$ with $a, b, c$ respectively to see if it is any easier to prove it and this is the new form:
$$2(\|a\|+\|b\|+\|c\|)\le\|a+b+c\|+\|a+b-c\|+\|b-a+c\|+\|b-a-c\|$$

My hunch is that showing that $d(r,s)=\|r\|+\|s\|-\|r+s\|$ is a distance might help using $d(r,s)\le d(r,t)+d(t,s)$.

I found these links that seem to have the solution:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167685/absolute-value-inequality-for-complex-numbers

[Inequality for absolute values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793905/inequality-for-absolute-values)

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Shaun: Thanks for the comments. Made the post much better.

Answer (score -1):

After squaring of the both sides we need to probe that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\|x\|\|x+y+z\|+\|y\|\|z\|\right)\geq\sum_{cyc}\|x+y\|\|x+z\|,$$ which is true by the triangle inequality for complex numbers:
$$\|x\|\|x+y+z\|+\|y\|\|z\|=\|x^2+xy+xz\|+\|yz\|\geq$$
$$\geq\|x^2+xy+xz+yz\|=\|x+y\|\|x+z\|.$$
It seems that for vectors it's not true.

Comment: I think this proof needs a bit more work because for vectors $\||x\||\||y\|| \ne ||xy||$. What is the definition of xy for vectors?

Comment: @Saeed Yes, you are right. I'll fix it soon.